# Creating (2) dockers for a react app w/ a node front end. How do I adjust the proxy settings to prevent breaking the app if it's run natively?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, docker-compose

I have a client/server react+node.js app.  The front end communicates with the API via the proxy in packages.json.

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:5000/"
```

I can get both the client and API to come up by running them in two separate docker containers via docker-compose.  This allows an alias to be used in place of localhost:

```
"proxy": "http://server:5000/"
```

That fixes docker -- but breaks it if the app is going to be run natively outside of docker.  It cannot resolve server to localhost (or an IP.)

Is there a way for the app to detect if it's being run in a docker and use another proxy?  Or a way for it to fail-over to a second proxy if the first one times out?

Answer (score 1):

If you are running the webpack build in your docker container you can provide the proxy url by passing in an environment variable from docker to webpack using the -e flag:

```
docker run -e "PROXY_URL=http://server:5000/"
```

Then you can provide PROXY_URL to react using webpack's [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/):

```
plugins: [
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    PROXY_URL: JSON.stringify(process.env.PROXY_URL)
  })
]
```

Then you can just read PROXY_URL as a variable inside your app.

Comment: This is amazing.  Thanks!  But....  any other solutions you can think of if webpack isn't being used?

Comment: Well if you can provide some more details on your build system and environment I might be able to give you more ideas.